# How do I exclude the current user from the search?

Tags: views, search

In a normal Views user search, you can simply add a `User: Current` filter to remove the logged-in user from the search results.

I have a Search API Views search of a Solr index of users, and I want to do the same thing.  However, the `User:Current` filter is not available.  How can I achieve the same function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a simple module using [hook_views_pre_view](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!search_api!search_api.api.php/function/hook_search_api_query_alter/7).

1. Be sure to index the User ID
2. Under Filter Criteria, add **Indexed User: User ID**, and set it to NOT EQUAL TO and use 0 (anonymous user, which will never be in this list).
3. Using `MY_MODULE_views_pre_view` with the [global user value](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/user/7), replace **0** with the UID of the current user.

```
function MY_MODULE_views_pre_view(&$view) {
  global $user;
  if ($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME') {
    if ($user->uid) {
      $view->display['default']->handler->options['filters']['uid']['value'] = $user->uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the way to go.  How exactly do I do #3?  I don't see where **USERID** is passed to the query.  I tried a different approach based on the example in `search_api_query_alter()` (https://www.drupal.org/node/2502819), but ran into a wall.

Comment: @PatrickKenny I updated my answer, I just had to set up Solr locally to test it. You don't actually need the search_api hook, you can just use a normal views hook. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!  Since my view has multiple panes, I had to change the code to use `$view->current_display` instead of `default` as follows: `$view->display[$view->current_display]->handler->options['filters']['uid']['value'] = $user->uid;`